# old mysql & php hangs all of a sudden

Tags: php, mysql

php 5.2.9 mysql 5.0.67

The following function hangs after years of working fine. Nothing has been changed on the server, at list that we know of:

```
function getSettings($module= 'core')
{
        global $db,$_SETTINGS_CACHE,$_SETTINGS,$JSON;

        $SettingsQuery = $db->query("SELECT data,displayorder,title,module,encoded FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."settingsfields WHERE module='$module'");
        while($Setting = $db->fetch($SettingsQuery))
        {

                $data = iif ($Setting['encoded'],$JSON->decode($Setting['data']),$Setting['data']);

                $module = $Setting['module'];
                $title = $Setting['title'];

                $_SETTINGS[$module][$title] = $data;
                $_SETTINGS_CACHE[$title] = $data;
        }

        return $_SETTINGS[$module];
}
```

what I see with strace is thats it gets stuck at:

```
write(4, "V\0\0\0\3SELECT data,displayorder,ti"..., 90) = 90
read(4, "\1\0\0\1\5E\0\0\2\3def\vdb_site\16settin"..., 16384) = 1802
```

until max execution time pass

Is there something wrong with the function?
Why would it stop working all of a sudden?

I should say that

```
SELECT data,displayorder,title,module,encoded FROM settingsfields WHERE module='core'
```

from mysql works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Well there is not one specific/definite answer to this but you can check at multiple places, like server load, sql logs and php logs along with network issues or latency

Comment: I opened sql log, there's just this query and then nothing. What I did was run the command with strace /path/to/php5 index.php and got what is in the original post. No other info is available anywhere

Comment: Oh also do check has the size of data exponentially increased over the year and is the table indexed with column name on the where clause

Comment: it's a setting table. There's almost nothing in it. Running from mysql prompt it output within a second.

Comment: Can you perform a sanity check for the function param? And how many records you have for the param you are passing to it?

Comment: If the code stopped working, and the query still works, the obvious next thing to look at is the data - maybe there is now a record in the DB which is somehow causing problems.  You need to debug and find which record, and from there, why it is causing problems.  Log or `echo` the retrieved data at the start of each iteration to see if it iterates at all, and if so which record it hangs on.  The only thing happening in the loop is the mysterious `iif()` function, so likely you're going to have to trace through it, log/`echo` various stages of whatever it is doing, etc.

Comment: I put echo $data; die(); at the end of the while loop, it prints and die. I put echo $data; there, it just hangs again before even printing.

Comment: I found the faulting line in the table. Thanks for your help.